# HTML input array parsing in Python (GAE)

Tags: python, html, arrays, google-app-engine, input

I'm two days in to Python and GAE, thanks in advance for the help.

I have an input array in HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" name="p_item[]">
<input type="text" name="p_item[]">
<input type="text" name="p_item[]">
```

I want to parse the input in Python, and I'm trying this, which isn't working:

```
items = self.request.get('p_item')
for n in range(1,len(items)):
  self.response.out.write('Item '+n+': '+items[n])
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I've never used GAE but I'm guessing you want values in your p_item 'array' name values. For example, `p_item[field1]` or `p_item[field2]`? For now, I have a feeling you might be having the problem that `len(items) == 0`.

Comment: Okay, I got this to work, but by removing the brackets[] in the HTML. Is this an accepted standard, to simply have multiple occurrences of a variable name in one HTML document, without the use of arrays?

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get an unexpected result? Do you get an error? Which one? In which line? What else have you tried so far?

Comment: It should probably be unique within the form because it specifies the key for the key-value pair you submit. I don't think `self.request.get('p_item')` will be able to determine which value you want to submit if you name multiple inputs the same thing within one form...

Comment: Scratch my comment above, it doesn't work. I'm only getting the first instance, tjko, you're right.

Comment: Figured it out - but can't answer my own question yet, as I am new. Solution is to use self.request.get_all, which returns a list. In HTML, variable name should not have brackets. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Steven The use of brackets is a PHP oddity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your html to this

```
<input type="text" name="p_item">
<input type="text" name="p_item">
<input type="text" name="p_item">
```

and use the self.request.get_all() method http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_all

p.s. For reference, there is no concept of arrays for GET/POST data, your form gets transformed a key=value string separated by '&' e.g.

```
p_item=1&p_item=3&p_item=15
```

etc, it's up to the web framework to interpret whether a parameter is an array.

Edit: oops, just read the comments that you figured this out already, oh well :P

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing some debugging if this sort of issue comes up. Make things simple and write out your variable values and ensure you get what you expect at each step. Do something like the following:

```
<form method="get">
   <input type="text" name="single_key" />
   <input type="text" name="array_key[some_key]" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And see what happens when running the following Python on the backend:

```
single_value = self.request.get('single_key')
self.response.out.write(str(single_value))

array_value = self.request.get('array_key')
self.response.out.write(str(array_value))
```

Based on the output you should have a better idea of what to get the desired results or how to add more detail to your question if you still don't understand a certain behavior.